# Entering multiple lists at once in SQLi Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, insert

I am using the following command to enter list values in a SQLi Database.

```
    sql_comm = "INSERT INTO Revisions (Work_ID,Rev_No,Name,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"
    data = (wid,i,rev_name,rev_date)
    crsr.execute(sql_comm,data)
    sql_com2 = "INSERT INTO Revisions (Field,New_Value) VALUES (?,?)"
    for elem in zip(changes,vals):
        crsr.execute(sql_com2,elem)
    connection.commit()
```

This is the resulting output.

```
Work_ID Rev_No  Name                                   Date               Field      New Value                                          
172      1      Raul Gitta <raoul_g@ware.23biz> 2021-10-21T10:08:10.653Z   null       null
null    null    null    null                                      System.Rev            2
null    null    null    null                                      System.AuthorizedDate 2021-10-20T06:42:01.32Z
null    null    null    null                                      System.RevisedDate    2021-10-21T10:08:10.653Z
null    null    null    null                                      System.ChangedDate    2021-10-20T06:42:01.32Z
null    null    null    null                                      System.Watermark      198
```

Is there a way to avoid these `null` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the null values stem from that fact that they are not inserted in the appropriate INSERT query. It might be easier to use lists for the parameters instead of tuples, since lists are mutable.

Something like:

```
data = [wid,i,rev_name,rev_date]
sql_com2 = "INSERT INTO Revisions (Work_ID,Rev_No,Name,Date,Field,New_Value) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
for elem in zip(changes,vals):
    crsr.execute(sql_com2,data + list(elem))
 connection.commit()
```

Comment: `crsr.execute(sql_comm,data)` this won't be needed...right?

Comment: Correct, I forgot to delete from the copy/paste. Edit in progres.......

Comment: So, we cannot have like 1 row for the single value columns and multiple rows for the columns which have lists as values and the respective rows for other columns remaining blank?

Comment: If you want blanks instead of null, then change the default in the schema to blank OR insert blanks. I'm a little confused because if those columns (Work_ID,Rev_No,Name,Date) are blank, how will you know which rows are "related"? Or maybe you need  add a new child table for Field, New_Values (with a parent key, presumbly). Clarification in the question may be helpful.